# Google Play developer console: beta version with different application id?

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to upload a production's apk with an application id, for example "com.domain.app" and another apk for the beta version named "com.domain.beta" within the same project on the console? Then how are the version numbers managed? Could I remove the beta apk whenever I want?

Comment: I know this, but I don't know if I can upload two different application id within the same project, one for production and the other for beta

Comment: So what the users see? Can they download them both?

Comment: When you use the suffix isn't it a different id? I mean, the one with beta looks different